# Why is an inductive load not desirable for a GTO circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, inductive

I was wondering why is an inductive load not good for a GTO circuit from a power electronics perspective.

Comment: what does a GTO do, why do you use it? What does an inductor do at that very moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GTO is a controlable switch .Like a scr it is turned on by positive signal on the gate .Unlike the scr it can be turned off with negative volts applied to the gate .This makes the device more useful.But if you turn the device off when significant current is flowing energy stored in circuit inductance can cause a nasty voltage spike destroying the device .The same would happen with a BJT,IGBT or Mosfet.This means that you should take the normal precautions like Snubbing ,clamping etc to ensure reliability.